# Energy consumption on Android Studio Profiler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

In Android Studio 3.2 there is a **Profiler** that let you know what is the energy consumption of your application.

We suspect a slow energy leak due to our application that reduces the battery autonomy of several hours.

With the Profiler we can say that there are no CPU, MEMORY and NETWORK activity while the application is in background and the phone in sleep mode (standby). But we can notice on the graph around every 5 seconds a very light ENERGY consumption.

I would like to know if this light ENERGY consumption (in purple on the graph) is normal or if it is something to worry about.

[image: Android Profiler]

I tried to select part of the graph to see events related to this energy bar but it says "No system events for the selected range or filter" like on this print screen below.

[image]

Do you have any ideas where does this energy comes from and if it is related to our application code implementation?

Comment: did you go through this? https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/energy-profiler

Comment: Yes I did go through this. Both my college and I have the same behaviour when selecting the energy bars. => "No system events for the selected range or filter". It's not showing the events as they say in the link you shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually did a test with a new empty project, only 1 activity doing nothing. 
The profiler is showing the same small and frequent energy pulse. So that's something that doesn't come from the implementation of the application.